# Sequence - stop at 90

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

You start with **0** and then proceed as follows:

**1**, **8**, **2**, **1**, **11**, **9**, **18**, **??**, **90**

- There's no other number after 90 in this sequence. In fact, it's  **impossible** to find!
- One of the numbers can be replaced by another number, but this sequence would take up *alot* more space if so, so I made an exception and made it simpler.

So, what is the **rule** of this sequence? What number is the **exception**(why)? And what two-digit number is missing?

EDIT: Made a mistake in the sequence! It's correct now. Guess, it will be easier now...

Comment: Does this need some kind of [tag:knowledge]-related tag?

Comment: No, not really. Its almost completely basic knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is:

> All numbers begin with the letter the previous one ends with

Thanks to @Stiv, we also know that:

> The number chosen is the lowest 1 or 2-digit number beginning with that letter that isn't already in the sequence.

Starting with 0:

> Zer**o** > **O**n**e** > **E**igh**t** > **T**w**o** > **O**n**e** > **E**leve**n** > **N**in**e** > **E**ightee**n** > **N**inetee**n** > **N**inety

You can't go further because

> no number begins with **y**

This may not be all there is to it though.

Comment: You got the correct rule! But not the correct missing two-digit number. How about the exception?

Comment: another could be rot13(avargrra). Nice work. :)

Comment: But still, why *exactly* these numbers?  Alot more resoning needed!

Comment: Like @MacGyver88 says your missing number is probably rot13(avargrra - vg'f gur YBJRFG ahzore bs srjre guna 3 qvtvgf ortvaavat jvgu gur ynfg yrggre bs gur cerivbhf, hfvat ahzoref guhf-sne-hahfrq vs ninvynoyr. 1 vf ercrngrq orpnhfr vg vf gur bayl bar ortvaavat jvgu B. V'z thrffvat gur BC yvzvgrq gur ehyr gb ahzoref bs srjre guna 3 qvtvgf, ryfr gurl'q unir unq bar-uhaqerq nsgre gur 2, juvpu jbhyq grezvangr gur frdhrapr noehcgyl, fvapr ab ybj ahzoref ortva jvgu Q.) Not sure about the exception - this rule seems pretty solid unless I've missed something amongst its constraints!

Comment: @Stiv, pretty sure you nailed it.

Comment: @Stiv Lrf, guvf vf gur pbeerpg ernfbavat. Naq gur rkprcgvba vf gur 1 nsgre 2(ybtvpnyyl vg fubhyq bs orra 100 naq nsgre gung "qrpvyyvba"(gnxr nybg bs fcnpr)) fb v znqr vg fvzcyre.

Comment: @ItsPete Edit your answer a little so I can give you the tick

Comment: @ItsPete Looks good now. Except that 18 and 11 switch place

Comment: @Prim3numbah So they do, I'd missed the change & edited now. Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: @ItsPete Yea, I didn't notice the mistake until after your answer. Good job :)